# Vim: Remap key to move to the next non-blank line (and vice versa)

Tags: vim, viml

I'm looking for a way to remap a key to move the cursor down to the next line, skipping any lines that only contain `\n` and a way to do the same only going up to the next line.

Essentially, I want to do the opposite of the { and } motions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are alternatives to DJ's mappings that play well with `hlsearch`:

- jump to next non-empty line

  ```
  nnoremap <key> :<C-u>call search('^.\+')<CR>
  ```
- jump to previous non-empty line

  ```
  nnoremap <otherkey> :<C-u>call search('^.\+', 'b')<CR>
  ```
- extend visual selection to next non-empty line

  ```
  xnoremap <key> :<C-u>k`\|call search('^.\+')\|normal! <C-r>=visualmode()<CR>``o<CR>
  ```
- extend visual selection to previous non-empty line

  ```
  xnoremap <otherkey> :<C-u>k`\|call search('^.\+', 'b')\|normal! <C-r>=visualmode()<CR>``o<CR>
  ```
- operate to next non-empty line

  ```
  omap <key> :<C-u>normal! v<key><CR>
  ```
- operate to previous non-empty line

  ```
  omap <otherkey> :<C-u>normal! v<otherkey><CR>
  ```

**Explanation…**

With `hlsearch` enabled, `/anything` will highlight every match. Since we are not actively *searching* for non-empty lines but merely *moving* to them, the resulting highlighting is pointlessly noisy.

By using `:help search()`, we bypass `hlsearch`and thus make the mappings a lot less noisy.

`<C-u>` is used to remove any accidental range before calling our function.

The visual mode mappings work like this:

1. we define the "previous mark" with `:help :k`,
2. we perform the search,
3. we run the following normal mode commands with `:help :normal`,
4. we retrieve the previous visual mode with `:help i_ctrl-r`, `:help "=`, and `:help visualmode()`,
5. we extend the visual selection to the location of the "previous mark" with `:help ''`,
6. and finally we move the cursor to the other end of the visual selection with `:help v_o`.

The operator pending mappings simply reuse the visual mode mappings.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you want to map these two, so I'll just use `{` and `}`. How about this?

```
nnoremap } /^\S<cr>
nnoremap { ?^\S<cr>
```

The explanation is pretty straightforward.

```
/           " Search forward
 ^          " For the start of a line
  \S        " Followed by a non-whitespace character
    <cr>    " Enter
```

The `?` mapping is the same except for searching backwards instead of forwards.

Of course for completeness, you'll want to add

```
nnoremap } /^\S<cr>
xnoremap } /^\S<cr>
onoremap } /^\S<cr>
nnoremap { ?^\S<cr>
xnoremap { ?^\S<cr>
onoremap { ?^\S<cr>
```

This will make it work as an argument to an operator (e.g. `d{`) and in visual mode.